# How can I simplify this expressions to get one formula?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, geometric-series

the expressions are :
f(1) = (a^0)
f(2) = (a+1)
f(3) = (a^2+a+1)

and the answer is f(n)= (a^n-1) /a-1, it is the formula for the sum of the geometric series right ?

I have tried to find the formula but I stuck in this : 
f(1)= a^(n-1)
f(2)= a^(n-1)+a^(n-2)
f(3)= a^(n-1)+a^(n-2)+a^(n-3)
how can I make the 3 equations below to find that the formula is the sum of geometric series ,,

Comment: You use the ^ in two different ways. By f^1 do you mean $f(1)$ or $f_1$?  On the right it looks like normal exponentiation.

Comment: You wrote $f^1=a^0$. Did you mean $f_0=a_0$? I imagine you did.

Comment: @TheCount:  I don't think so, I think OP means $f(1)=a^0=1$.  It is one term of the geometric series.

Comment: @RossMillikan It seems like that would be an odd way to write the first term, but also I see your contextual argument too.

Comment: @AsterZen here is a website to help you format your question so it is easier to understand and answer: https://latex.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_LaTeX_symbols

Comment: yes that's right, sorry I made a mistake, I have change them, thank you @RossMillikan

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that by f^1 you mean $f(1)$ and so on there is no way to find that $f(n)$ is the sum of the geometric series aside from recognizing the pattern.  Nothing in the data you are given tells you what $f(4)$ is.  The geometric series is (to my eye) the simplest explanation for the first three terms and problems where you are given the first few terms of a series or sequence are intended to be solved by finding the simplest pattern (to the setter's eye) and extending it.

Whenever somebody posts a sequence or series problem there are those who complain (I would say correctly but pedantically) that you can extend the sequence or series any way you want so there is no solution.  I believe the setter owes us enough information to make one solution stand out as the simplest and it can be a fun problem to find it.  Here  I would go with the geometric series as you suggest.